# In the Local server our Ajax code is working, at the same time when we deploy in the Live server its not working

Tags: javascript, asp.net-ajax

```
dltlogtaskcreate(eactive, eName, eDesg, loginName);
```

the above function is working fine

```
logtaskcreate(eactive, eName, eDesg, loginName);
```

This function is not working in the live server,

The Ajax code is working fine in the local server server, but not working in the live server, but when we click the "save" button twice and also When we give Inspect element and debug the code it is working, actually we need to get the output when we click the SAVE button on a single click instead of clicking that twice.

```js
  success: function(data) {
    var activevalue = data.d.Active;
    var taskidvalue = data.d.Task_ID;
    var taskname = data.d.Task_Name;
  },

  error: function(error) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(error));
  }

});
dltlogtaskcreate(eactive, eName, eDesg, loginName);

logtaskcreate(eactive, eName, eDesg, loginName);
```

```js
function logtaskcreate(activevalue, taskidvalue, taskname, loginName) {
  var month = new Array();
  month[0] = "Jan";
  month[1] = "Feb";
  month[2] = "Mar";
  month[3] = "Apr";
  month[4] = "May";
  month[5] = "Jun";
  month[6] = "Jul";
  month[7] = "Aug";
  month[8] = "Sep";
  month[9] = "Oct";
  month[10] = "Nov";
  month[11] = "Dec";
  //alert(month);
  var currentdate = new Date();
  //alert(currentdate)
  var dd = currentdate.getDate();
  if (dd < 10) {
    dd = '0' + dd;
  }
  var min = currentdate.getMinutes();
  if (min < 10) {
    min = '0' + min;
  }
  var hour = currentdate.getHours();
  if (hour < 10) {
    hour = '0' + hour;
  }
  var datetime = dd + "-" +
    (month[currentdate.getMonth()]) + "-" +
    currentdate.getFullYear() + " " +
    hour + ":" +
    min;
  alert(datetime);
  var newtask = "";
  //var ischecked = $('#chkactive').is(":checked");
  if (activevalue == "Yes") {

    newtask = "Task Created and " + "active" + " by " + loginName;
  } else {
    newtask = "Task Created and " + "inactive" + " by " + loginName;
  }
  alert(newtask);

  $.ajax({

    async: true,
    url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Log')/items",
    cache: false,
    method: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify({
      '__metadata': {
        'type': 'SP.Data.LogListItem'
      },
      'Date': datetime,
      'Task_Action': newtask,
      'Task_ID': taskidvalue,
      'Task_Name': taskname,

    }),

    headers: {
      "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
      "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
      "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
    },

    success: function(data) {

      //swal({ title: "", text: "Item created successfully", type: "success", confirmButtonText: "OK" }, function (isConfirm) {
      //    if (isConfirm) { location.reload(); }
      //});

      //  getItems();

    },

    error: function(error) {
      alert(JSON.stringify(error));

    }

  });
  //  return deferred.promise();
  // });

}
```

Comment: Please explain what happens when it's "*not working*". Sidenote: in javascript you can write `var month = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar",` etc. `]; `

Comment: When we save the form the values will get save in the three list, but only two list are getting updated when we click the save button , remaining one list is not updating in the live server, these all happens when we click the SAVE button once.